# R stuck in loading sqldf package

Tags: r, sqldf, proto

I have been trying to use the sqldf package in R, but it simply stopped at loading required package "proto". Like this:

> library(sqldf)
>   Loading required package: DBI
>   Loading required package: gsubfn
>   Loading required package: proto

I'm using R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03) -- "Masked Marvel". Could someone please let me know what was missing here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The next required package is `tcltk`, which [sometimes poses problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219747/sqldf-package-in-r-querying-a-data-frame): try `options(gsubfn.engine = "R")` just before loading `sqldf`.

Comment: Read the troubleshooting section of the sqldf home page: http://sqldf.googlecode.com

Comment: Thanks for the comments, Vincent's solution works like a charm!

Comment: @G.Grothendieck the link is broken.  Would you mind reposting correct link if you find it?  Thanks!

Comment: It was moved to github when googlecode shut down: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf